# Change string to date in certain timezone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a date as string in format yyyy-mm-dd & timezone stored in another variable t in format like (GMT -05:00) Eastern Time. I want to obtain the date object with this date in this timezone in Javascript/appscript. The time in date object should be 00.00.00.000 only & timezone should as in the variable.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+time+timezone+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `new Date('2021-01-01T00:00:00-05:00')`

Comment: @Keith Both dateString & timezone are variable & also I do not want to do character parsing. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

```
function dateStringsForDifferentTimezones() {
  let oA = [['Date String','TimeZone']];
  for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    oA.push([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), `GMT-${i}`, "E MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"),`${-i}`]);
  }
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(1, 1, oA.length, 2 ).setValues(oA);
}
```